# How to round a value to a certain number of decimal places, in Python?

Tags: python

Given a number I want to find what is its value with the hundredth place closest to 2, 5, 6, or 0.

Is there a rounding function that does this or how do I do it programmatically?

For example, 2.567 would give 2.566, 2.5652 would give 2.565, 2.5613 would give 2.562.

Comment: Could you provide an example or two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something called the Python Documentation:

> round(*number[, ndigits]*)
>
> Return the floating point value number
>   rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is
>   omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number.
>   Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus
>   ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away
>   from 0 (so. for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).
>
> Note The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
>   is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
>   can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point
>   Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

Thus rounding can be as simple as:

```
print round(2.235, 2)

# Output: 2.24
```

From here on, you can write some simple code that measures the distance the hundredths place is closest to from 2, 5, 6, 0.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear, but hopefully something like this will get you headed in the right direction:

```
vals   = [ 0, 2, 5, 6 ]
number = 4.296

distances = [ abs(x - number) for x in vals]
closest   = vals[distances.index(min(distances))]
```

That gets you the value in the list to which `number` is closest.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP is after as it's a big vague, but will point out the above can be written more concisely, efficiently and Pythonically as: `closest = min(vals, key=lambda L: abs(number -  L))`

Comment: @JonClements Oh wow, right on! :)

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the fractional part starting at the hundredth digit, you could bump up the `num` by multiplying by 10, and then separating the whole from the fractional part. For example, 3.14159 would become 31.4159, and the whole part would be 31, and the fractional part would be 0.4159.

Now, you could use `bisect.bisect` to pick the digit (e.g. 0, 2, 5 or 6) closest to the fractional part:

```
import bisect
def closest_hundredth(num, digits=[0, 2, 5, 6]):
     digits = [d/10.0 for d in digits] + [1.0]
     num *= 10
     whole = int(num)
     frac = num-whole
     boundary_vals = [(digits[i]+digits[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(digits)-1)]
     idx = bisect.bisect(boundary_vals, frac)
     rounded_frac = digits[idx]
     new_num = whole + rounded_frac
     new_num /= 10
     return new_num

tests = [
     (3.14159, 3.15),
     (3.156, 3.16),
     (3.13159, 3.12),
     (0, 0),
     (0.01, 0.02),
     (0.011, 0.02),
     (0.08, 0.10)
     ]

for num, answer in tests:
     result = closest_hundredth(num)
     assert result == answer
```

Using `bisect.bisect` here may be overkill since there are only four choices -- an if-statement might be quicker. But I find it a readable way to express the idea without having to write the cumbersome if-statements. It also scales well (with complexity `O(log(n))` instead of `O(n)` for the `if-statements`) if there were many boundary values to choose from.